# Sql Server Management Studio hangs after executing tasks from Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am having a consistent and very frustrating problem with my Management Studio -- SQL Server 2008 R2, SP2.

For a little while after I open up the program it is fine. Then, usually after right-clicking  on a  table in the Object Explorer and selecting "Select Top 1000 Rows", it will start to hang if I attempt to execute any more tasks using the Object Explorer -- or even if I just type in a query in a new query window.

The first time it hangs, it may be for just 10 - 15 seconds. But as I go on, it starts hanging for as long as 15 minutes (usually I don't have the patience to wait, but I just did a test to see how long it would take to complete the query).

Ssms.exe starts using 25% of the CPU time, and the memory used increases steadily by 7 - 9 MB per second. Eventually it gets as high as 1.5G. Of course, long before this time I have usually killed the process and opened up Management Studio again. At this point I can work for a little while before it hangs up again. On big projects I am constantly having to close the program and open it up again.

Any ideas??? The tables I am attempting to view, by the way, may be very large, but it also hangs on very small ones with perhaps only 10 records. The size of the table does not seem to be a factor. It does often show "disconnected" in the status bar while it is hanging and increasing in memory, so possibly it is having a problem connecting for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Open up task manager.  Is the Network Utilization going high?  If it is pegged, then you have a bottle neck between your laptop and the server.

Otherwise, there is something wrong with SSMS on your laptop.  Did you install anything new lately?

Try operation from another machine as a baseline.  If it works there, then it is your machine.

Good luck.